# My ubuntu laptop takes too much time to boot

Tags: system-installation

It always shows a short text mentioning"errors".
For example, aborting error...due to previous error.
How can I avoid that text when starting up my laptop? Thanks.

Comment: You've provided no Ubuntu product or release details, are we to guess?  Have you used any of the inbuilt functions to *analyze blame* etc for your *unstated* product/release?  We cannot comment on any error(s) or message(s) you see unless you provide details of them for us to read.

Comment: First steps: Open a Terminal / Shell / Bash and check `systemd-analyze blame | less` and `dmesg | less` for clues on what trouble might be there. Note that some software (might) attempt(s) to e.g. initialize hardware that **does not exist** (in your computer) and report that as an "error" or "failure"

Comment: SGX disabled by bios. ACPI BIOS error (bug): could not resolve symbol. ACPI error : aborting method.....those are some phrases shown in the text. And it takes time to start up.